# how to sending Dynamic Id sending getElementById to js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-helpers

```
                                        <div id="product-zoom-gallery" class="product-image-gallery">
                                            @foreach (var item in Model.Images)
                                            {
                                                <a onclick="myFunction('@item')" class="product-gallery-item active" href="#" @*onclick="changeImg('/@item');"*@
                                               data-image="/@item"
                                               data-zoom-image="/@item">
                                                    <img id="myImg @item"  src="/@item"
                                                     >
                                                </a>
                                            }


                                        </div>
```

I want to send a dynamic ID to `myFunction(item)`, where "item" is my dynamic ID and I want to send that like this to
getElementById method:

```
        function myFunction(item){
            var string = `"myImg ${item}"`
            alert(string);
            var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

            var img = document.getElementById(`"${string}"`);
            var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
            var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
            img.onclick = function () {
                modal.style.display = "block";
                modalImg.src = this.src;
                captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
            }

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            span.onclick = function () {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

But the `var img` does not work for me. I would expect from `var img = document.getElementById(`"${string}"`);`, to find my img tag.

Comment: An id should not contain spaces

Comment: You put double quotes INSIDE the value when setting the `string` variable, and then when using it in `document.getElementById(\`"${string}"\`)` you add ANOTHER set of double quotes. All of them should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Whitespaces are not supported in the `id` attribute. In general, you should stick to alphanumeric ASCII-friendly characters (and not start with a number). Besides letters and numbers, you can also use `_` or `-` as separators.
2. There's some redundant quotations (`"`) in your template literals (between the backticks ``), since the backticks already convert its content into a string automatically.

So your code would become:

```html
<img id="myImg-item">
```

```js
function myFunction(id){
    var string = `myImg-${id}`
    alert(string);
    
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var img = document.getElementById(string);
```

Now if you call your function: `myFunction('item')`, it will assemble the ID `"myImg-item"` and the getElementById lookup should succeed.

For more information, please read up on the `id` attribute on the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Comment: getElementById lookup it is failed my code does not work after on the var img = document.getElementById(string);

Comment: now i knwo why the var img = document.getElementById(string); does not work because my id has sended to the method like this(myImg-FilesItem38069707322680384-5832364197407734490_121.jpg) insted like this(myImg-Files\Item\638069707322680384-5832364197407734490_121.jpg)